# How do I install a package locally with Local-Npm

Tags: reactjs, npm

I have been told here that I could locally add globally installed packages using `local-npm`

I am aware that this is not a good practice, but as I may be forced to work offline for a few weeks I am desperate to get this set up so I do not face issues if I need any of my most commonly used packages.

I have already installed all the packages that I will need for the following weeks globally and I am now trying to understand how to use `local-npm`.

Am talking about front-end packages for me to use with `react`, such as `redux`, `react-router`, etc.

I have understood that I need to first:

- install `local-npm` globally (done)
- run `npm-local` in my project (the terminal does not recognize this command)
  I have also tried `local-npm run start` with no success anyways.
- set the registry to `npm set registry http://127.0.0.1:5080`
- then install whatever a want `npm intall redux-thunk`, for instance.

I am surely doing something wrong.

After a set the registry, turn the wiFi off and try to install `npm install <package name>` in my project nothing happens.

THanks and sorry for the dumb question as I am still a beginner to `npm` and still going to start the `back-end` journey.

P.S - I have read the [Local-npm docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-npm) so please don't answer just pointing me there, but please give me a `demo` example, or something alike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an entirely separate technology, but I'd like to suggest that you try out pnpm. https://pnpm.js.org. It's essentially a drop in replacement for npm.

Pnpm works by caching your installs to one central location and then creating symlinks to that location to the node_modules folder.

Pnpm will allow you to work offline, provide very fast installs (as it's just a symlink), and you don't need to pollute your global installs.

https://pnpm.js.org/en/cli/install there's an option for installing fully offline once the modules are cached: `pnpm i --offline`

Comment: thanks! I will take a look and return to you asap in case I have any doubts

Comment: so I start by running ```npx pnpm add -g pnpm```? to install it globally? What is the difference of running the first command to just using ```pnpm install```?

Comment: The first command uses pnpm to install itself (because you don't have pnpm installed yet) so that it can be used to upgrade itself. The second command uses pnpm to install something with an already existing pnpm. `add` and `install` are synonyms

Comment: where do I run ```pnpm i --offline```? inside my project folder? and when I try using any command starting with ```pnpm``` it does not reconize ```pnpm``` I get ```command not found: pnpm```

Comment: You'd use `pnpm install` in your project folders (after you delete any existing node_modules folders). If pnpm is saying that the command isn't found, did you globally install it by running that first command? For the offline installs, you need to let it build up it's cache first by installing modules with it normally.

Comment: Yup. And if you have an old project, you can delete the node modules folder and run `pnpm install`. The only thing I've run into that I haven't gotten it to work with yet is Angular, which for some reason doesn't show styles when installed with pnpm

Comment: I did install it globally ```npx pnpm add -g pnpm
npx: instalou 1 em 6.944s
Nothing to stop. No server is running for the store at /Users/Dev/.pnpm-store/2
Packages: +1
+
Resolving: total 1, reused 0, downloaded 1, done

/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.12.0/pnpm-global/3:
+ pnpm 4.14.4
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214470/discussion-between-zachary-haber-and-aliosh-r).